# React Native - Animate text from left to center of screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I move this text from left to center using react native Animated API?

```
const animate = () => {
   // TODO - Animate text from 27.5 left, to center of screen
}

return (
   <View style={styles.header}>
      <Animated.Text style={{ marginLeft: 27.5 }}>
         Header
      </Animated.Text>
   </View>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I righly recommend you to read the official React Native's Documentation: https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated

You can start by creating a reference from an animated value, like so:

```js
const moveAnimation = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
```

And pass it to your animated componente:

```js
...
 <Animated.Text style={[styles.text, {marginLeft: moveAnimation}]}>
...
```

Finally, we need to create your animation:

```js
// Note that i used Dimensions from React-Native and subtracted 50 from it
// because i have a padding in my View component

const animate = () => {
    Animated.timing(moveAnimation, {
      toValue: (Dimensions.get('window').width/2)-50,
      duration: 200
    }).start();
  }
```

Now, you can simply call our animate function to trigger it.

I wrote this Snack so you can see it running: https://snack.expo.io/@filipemelo032/animation

Comment: am I right to say this will only work if the text is of known width?

Comment: Hey, @DomVinyard, great question. But yeah, I don't think you necessarily need to know the text's width. Could explain a bit more about your use case?

Comment: if your text is exactly 100 wide, then this animation will correctly move it from the far left, to being left-aligned at the middle of the screen (window.width/2) to being centre aligned at the middle of the screen (-50). If the text is of unknown width (let's say, a username) then you would also need to measure the text item's width in order to achieve this